# Git - ignore config files

Tags: git, security, gitlab, gitignore

To start off - I have read a lot of questions regarding this topic so I am aware of the following approaches:

- `.gitignore`
- `--skip-worktree`
- `--assume-unchanged`

This question is more trying to satisfy my own personal preference on how to handle configuration files.

I have tried the `.gitignore` and `--skip-worktree` approaches and yes they work but they don't satisfy my preference for how to handle configuration files which is why I'm looking for another solution. I believe `--assume-unchanged` achieves the same result as `--skip-worktree` even though they are different so I opted not to try it anymore (yes I've read many questions and documentations regarding these flags).

Here are my problems:

#### `.gitignore`

The reason I don't like this is approach is that I have to name my config file something like `config.default.php` and have to remember to make a copy of it and rename it to `config.php` - which is included in the `.gitignore` file.

#### `--skip-worktree`

I don't like this that much because every developer who clones the remote repository has to remember to run the command.

---

So I guess the real question is: ***"Is there a way to ignore a config file where each developer doesn't have to run a command for every clone and not having to rename and copying a default config file?"***. Basically I want something ready out-of-the-box right after cloning, no other steps necessary other than supplying the necessary configuration values for each parameter.

Comment: Why not have both config.default.php (default values) and config.php (overriden values)? Load config.default.php 1st then config.php. Then ignore config.php

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis the `config.php` file contains values that are specific to each developer so it shouldn't be stored in the remote repository as it could contain sensitive data.

Comment: That's why it should be in .gitignore. But there is no need to copy config.default.php to config.php since you load both.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis So you're saying each developer needs to create a `config.php` file right after cloning? That's one of the things I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not necessary. config.php can be included only if it exists. Either use `@include()` or `is_file('config.php') AND include('config.php)`

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis I think you're missing the point. The default config file has blank values so each developer will have to supply their own sensitive values on that `config.php` file after cloning. I'm trying to avoid having the developers create another file.

Comment: They have to edit the faile anyway. They might as well create it (or copy it from a template file) - it really makes no difference. Other than that there is no way git will clone a file and not track it (unless you manually ignore it every time)

Answer (score 3):

If an application can work without config files (by figuring things out itself) it should do so.

When a config file is *necessary*, one *should not* be able to to run the application as-is, especially if sensitive data is required.

In that case, using `default` files (with sensible defaults and comments about what values to set) is a time-honored tradition. And ignoring the real config files (so they cannot be accidentally uploaded) is a sensible precaution from a standpoint of security.

How one magages the configuration of a server (or group of servers) is to a certain degree a matter of opinion and taste.
But putting the config files in the source repo for each application is *definitely* not the right answer!

One would at least expect the sysadmin to use a private repo for *all* configuration files for a certain server, and maybe even for a group of servers so that config files can be shared.

Comment: I couldn't follow your last 2 paragraphs but other than that I agree 100% with you. All I'm trying to do is to simplify it for developers. Clone repo. Supply necessary config values. Start developing. I'm just trying to eliminate the step of duplicating a file or issuing a command after cloning the repo.

Comment: How do you want to "supply necessary config values" *without* running a command?

Comment: Just modify the config file (with blank values) that is stored in the remote repo and just start working on tasks.

Comment: If there are no other options then I'm going to use the `.gitignore` method but I _really_ want to eliminate the step of copying `config.default.php` as `config.php`.

Comment: Let me be blunt. A developer that is not willing to copy, read and edit a config file should *not* be running any server whatsoever. Let alone a PHP server.

Comment: I also agree. `.gitignore` it is.